# Try to XOR a byte string aginst a single character key

Tags: python, cryptography, xor

I am trying to create an encrypted hex string using the XOR operation. I want to encode my_message. I want to XOR each character in `my_message` against `my_key`. I converted both of them to bytes and then passed them into my `xor_encrypt` method to perform the operation and return `encrypt_byte` which will be printed out as a hex encoded string. I am getting an error on the XOR operation: **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'int' and 'bytes'**. I am not sure how to correct this, because from my current understanding `bytes([b ^ byte_key])` should convert them both to bytes correct? I am somewhat new to cryptography and I am trying my best to understand. Any help is appreciated, feel free to ask questions I will be here to answer them for a while. Thank you in advance!

```py
# My encryption code
# Take in out byte_msg and XOR it against the byte_key
def xor_encrypt(byte_msg, byte_key):
    encrypt_byte = b''
    for b in byte_msg:
        encrypt_byte += bytes([b ^ byte_key])
    return encrypt_byte

# Ascii encoded
my_msg = 'Execute order 66'
my_key = 'b'
# Convert ASCII message and key to Bytes 
byte_msg = bytes(my_msg.encode("utf-8"))
print(byte_msg)
key_array = bytes(my_key.encode("utf-8"))
print(key_array)

# Print out the XOR'd message as a hex encoded string
print(f"XOR'd message: {xor_encrypt(byte_msg, key_array).hex()}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not `xor` strings, binary or not. So you convert each character in the string to its ASCII value and then `^`. Then convert the result to a character and finally encode it.

```
def xor_encrypt(byte_msg, byte_key):
    encrypt_byte = b''
    for b in byte_msg:
        encrypt_byte += chr(ord(b) ^ ord(byte_key)).encode()
    return encrypt_byte

# Ascii encoded
my_msg = 'Execute order 66'
my_key = 'b'
print(f"XOR'd message: {xor_encrypt(my_msg, my_key).hex()}") # XOR'd message: 271a0701171607420d10060710425454
```

Comment: Oh okay, that makes much more sense! This will help me a lot! Thank you!

Comment: I will after I try them out!  :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you converted the *result* of the operation to bytes.  The operation itself failed, because you didn't convert the operands.  Instead:

```
bytes(b) ^ bytes(byte_key)
```

You also inexplicably made a list of the result, and then wanted to convert that one-element list to `bytes`.  I removed that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't XOR `bytes` strings but `bytes` can be iterated as integers. You can XOR those, build them into a `bytearray` and convert to the final form from there.

```
# My encryption code
# Take in out byte_msg and XOR it against the byte_key
def xor_encrypt(byte_msg, byte_key):
    key = byte_key[0]
    return bytearray(val^key for val in byte_msg).hex()

# Ascii encoded
my_msg = 'Execute order 66'
my_key = 'b'
print(xor_encrypt(my_msg.encode("utf-8"), my_key.encode("ascii")))
```